# adding a key to HashMap without the value?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Is there a way to add a key to a HashMap without also adding a value? I know it seems strange, but I have a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>` amd I want to first be able to create keys as needed and then check if a certain key exists and, if so, put the appropriate value, namely the `ArrayList<Object>`

Was that confusing enough?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you're using a `Map<String, List<Object>>`, you're ***really*** looking for a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). I highly recommend using a third-party library such as Google Guava for this - see [Guava's `Multimaps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html).

```
Multimap<String, Object> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

// fill it
myMultimap.put("hello", "hola");
myMultimap.put("hello", "buongiorno");
myMultimap.put("hello", "สวัสดี");

// retrieve
List<String> greetings = myMultimap.get("hello");
                      // ["hola", "buongiorno", "สวัสดี"]
```

---

Java 8 update: I'm no longer convinced that every `Map<K, SomeCollection<V>>` should be rewritten as a multimap. These days it's quite easy to get what you need without Guava, thanks to [`Map#computeIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

```
Map<String, List<Object>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

// fill it
myMap.computeIfAbsent("hello", ignored -> new ArrayList<>())
  .addAll(Arrays.asList("hola", "buongiorno", "สวัสดี");

// retrieve
List<String> greetings = myMap.get("hello");
                      // ["hola", "buongiorno", "สวัสดี"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you want to do this. You can store `null` as a value for a key, but if you do how will be able to tell, when you do a `.get("key")` whether the key exists or if it does exist but with a `null` value? Anyway, see the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29).

Answer (score 3):

You can put `null` values. It is allowed by `HashMap`

You can also use a `Set` initially, and check it for the key, and then fill the map.

Comment: ...or just use Guava's Multimaps!

Comment: Hi Bozho - I found this question because I'm trying to do something similar, and your answer is really helpful. Would you be able to elaborate on how you would go about initialising a set and then converting it to a HashMap when you add objects to it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was confusing enough ;) I don't get *why* you want to store keys without values instead just putting empty arraylists instead of `null`.

Adding `null` may be a problem, because if you call

```
map.get("somekey");
```

and receive a `null`, then you do not know, if the key is not found or if it is present but maps to `null`...

Comment: If you add `null`, you can test with containsKey().

Comment: @sarumont - sure, but you have to *know* that only this method works for the map. I'd be surprised if a map returns `map.get("key") == null` and `map.contains("key") == true`...

Comment: it works with java.util.HashMap, at least. `map.put( "foo", null )` yields true for `map.containsKey( "foo" )` and null for `map.get( "foo" )`

Comment: @sarumont - sure: and exactly *that* behaviour would surprise me (in real code) ;)

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant now. :) I would also be surprised, but not overly so - I've unfortunately seen worse. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
//This program should answer your questions
import java.util.*;
public class attemptAddingtoHashMap { //Start of program

//MAIN METHOD #################################################

public static void main(String args[]) {  //main begins

Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> hmTrial = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>(); 

ArrayList alTrial = new ArrayList();//No values now

if (hmTrial.containsKey("first")) {
hmTrial.put("first", alTrial); }

else {hmTrial.put("first",alTrial);}
//in either case, alTrial, an ArrayList was mapped to the string "first"
//if you choose to, you can also add objects to alTrial later
System.out.println("hmTrial is " + hmTrial); //empty now
alTrial.add("h");
alTrial.add("e");
alTrial.add("l");
alTrial.add("l");
alTrial.add("o");
System.out.println("hmTrial is " + hmTrial);//populated now

   } //end of main
//#############################################################################################################

} //end of class

//Note - removing objects from alTrial will remove the from the hashmap
//You can copy, paste and run this code on https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/
```