# Map with ArrayList as the value in Java - Why use a third party library for this?

Tags: arraylist, dictionary, guava, java

I've recently found the need to use a `Map` with a `Long` as the key and an `ArrayList` of objects as the value, like this:

```
Map<Long, ArrayList<Object>>
```

But I just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6046027/2598115) that using a third-party library like Google Guava is recommended for this.  In particular, a `Multimap` is recommended instead of the above.

What are the main benefits of using a library to do something so simple?

Comment: Short answer: abstraction. It's like asking "Why use `ArrayList` when you can simply manage arrays manually?"

Comment: So it just makes your code more simple? edit: okay, I see what you're saying.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. That by itself should be reason enough to use it. If there are any performance differences, I'm not aware of them.

Comment: Simpler, easier to write, easier to read, easier to maintain.

Comment: Guava certainly has some cool classes that make certain tasks easier, but what you're doing is by no means uncommon or complicated.

Comment: I'm going to have to familiarize myself with more of this library to see if I can use it in enough places in my codebase to justify the inclusion of another library.  It's an Android project, so I'd like to keep the .apk as lightweight as possible.

Comment: @JDJ See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM), which is 5 years old, but covers Guava (foremly Google Collections) basics, including `Multimap` topic (it starts in second part, [here's direct link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ni_KEkHfto#t=5m51s)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PhilosophyExplained) details some reasoning and benefits.

For me the biggest reason would be reliability and testing. As mentioned it has been battle-tested at Google, is now very widely used elsewhere and has extensive unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

I like the `ArrayList` analogy given above. Just as `ArrayList` saves you from array-resizing boilerplate, `Multimap` saves you from list-creation boilerplate.

Before:

```
Map<String, List<Connection>> map =
    new HashMap<>();
for (Connection connection : connections) {
  String host = connection.getHost();
  if (!map.containsKey(host)) {
    map.put(host, new ArrayList<Connection>());
  }
  map.get(host).add(connection);
}
```

After:

```
Multimap<String, Connection> multimap =
    ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Connection connection : connections) {
  multimap.put(connection.getHost(), connection);
}
```

And that leads into the next advantage: Since Guava has committed to using `Multimap`, it includes utilities built around the class. Using them, the "after" in "before and after" should really be:

```
Multimap<String, Connection> multimap =
    Multimaps.index(connections, Connection::getHost);
```

[`Multimaps.index`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) is one of many such utilities. Plus, [the `Multimap` class itself provides richer methods than `Map<K, List<V>>`](https://plus.google.com/+googleguava/posts/djYfMk5daXz).